# Cannot import resource > "app/config/security.yml" from "/app/config/config.yml"

Tags: symfony

Im getting this error:

> FileLoaderLoadException: Cannot import resource
>   "app/config/security.yml" from "/app/config/config.yml".

The file security.yml is on the right path. This is my security.yml file:

```
jms_sapp/confiapp/config/security.yml
    secure_all_services: false
    exprapp/confiapp/config/security.yml

security:
    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

    providers:
        in_memory:
            memory:
                users:
                    user:  { password: userpass, roles: [ 'ROLE_USER' ] } 
                    admin: { password: adminpass, roles: [ 'ROLE_ADMIN' ] } 

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        login:
            pattern:  ^/demo/secured/login$
            security: false

        secured_area:
            pattern:    ^/demo/secured/
            form_login:
                check_path: /demo/secured/login_check
                login_path: /demo/secured/login
            logout:
                path:   /demo/secured/logout
                target: /demo/
            #anonymous: ~
            #http_basic:
            #    realm: "Secured Demo Area"

    access_control:
        #- { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: https }
        #- { path: ^/_internal/secure, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, ip: 127.0.0.1 }
```

Comment: Could you clarify what the first three lines are? It would also help to see your config.yml? Is the security.yml readable by the user running apache?

Comment: Just go over your file again check every little thing. Most times its just a syntax issue. Remove code and refresh and keep doing that till you find the line that is causing the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These three first lines, as @Sgoettschkes pointed out, are obviously problematic here. They do not conform to the YAML syntax standards. I second the question: what were you trying to achieve with them? Try to remove them and I'm 100% percent sure this error will disappear.

I heavily recommend that you use a good IDE which will highlight the YAML code for you, in case you don't use an IDE already (personally I use NetBeans and it handles YAML files pretty well). Syntax errors like this are very common and easy to spot, then.